# "Whatever improvements to filesystems will be made in the future"

Tags: grammar

Does this sentence break grammar?

> **Whatever improvements to filesystems will be made in the future**, it seems clear that  applications will remain to use the approach
>   established by POSIX and filesystems will have to cooperate.

I am thinking about something like

> Whatever improvements will be made to filesystems in the future (...)

Second suggestion, by Thistle

> It seems clear that applications will remain to use the approach established by POSIX and filesystems will have to cooperate with whatever improvements will be made to filesystems in the future.

Comment: This use of whatever seems grammatical, since it is used as a pronoun for the subject.

Comment: Apart from a complete re-write, I'd suggest that "*applications will remain **that** use the approach*" would be better.  ***to use*** sounds kind of like the applications will hang around specifically to exercise the old filesystems.

Comment: I think that *that* significantly changes meaning. Currently it means same applications changing implementation in future, and when applied, to new applications replacing current ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both grammatically okay but if you want to be idiomatic I'd avoid the 'will'. It seems to attribute a degree of intentionality to the improvements themselves.

I suggest:

*Whatever improvements are made to filesystems in the future...*

It's really a matter of style though. Note that the phrase "will remain to use" doesn't quite make sense.  You could either say, "will remain, that use" or "will continue to use".

Comment: +1 for pointing out the use of will! Something was bugging me, and I didn't quite catch it.

Comment: Actually there is a degree of intentionality. Improvements are made by people, they dont appear in the void. Accepted the part "will continue to use".

Comment: I meant that saying 'improvements will' sounds just a  little as though the improvements were willing themselves into being.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better phrasing: "Regardless of future improvements made to the filesystems, it seems clear that applications will remain in place in order to use the approach established by POSIX, and said filesystems will have to cooperate."

Comment: I would say "... applications will continue to exist which depend on the approach established by POSIX ....  But, regardless, "regardless" is the word!